# SSIS Failed Pre-Execute Phase check that the object exists in db

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package that brings data from Db2 to SQL Server for 20 tables. All my 20 DFT tasks are inside sequence container. the package is deployed in SSISDB and it intermittently throws the error for one particular object during pre-execute phase.

> An OLE DB error has occurred. Error Code - 0x80040E14
>   check that the object exists in the database.
>   Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned the error code 0xC02020E8"

Now the object exists in the destination database still it throws the error. The package has all the default settings.

I was reading that changing `DelayValidation` property to True can resolve the issue. But this `DelayValidation` exists at 1) the package level, 2) the connection manager level, and 3) at the DFT level. Where should I modify it?

Comment: Where you set it totally depends on what you need. Personally, I would do it on the relevant task that is failing.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. Do you think setting this property is the right solution and it will work?

Comment: Difficult to say, based on the information. If you're creating the object it's complaining about in the package, then yes it is.

Comment: I did change the property at DFT level only and still it failed. the next time it ran successfully. So the pattern here is one time fail, one time success and every time fails for same object. what could be the workaround here?

Comment: Also what I noticed is that the error is at source. Source is DB2. I have one connection manager for all 20 DB2 source tables but the failure happens only for one particular object.May be I can set delay validation at DB2 connection manager to True.